# Why am I getting an error when I try to use ngrok to create a http tunnel for my local host 5000 for Twilio?

Tags: python, twilio, ngrok

I am following this tutorial regarding `Twilio` and `Ngrok`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knxlmCVFAZI

I have written the same script as per the video:

```
import os 
from flask import Flask, request, redirect 
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sms",methods=['GET','POST'])
def sms_reply(): 
    resp = MessagingResponse() 

    resp.message("The robots are coming! Head for the hills!")

    return str(resp)


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run this in my terminal, I get a URL as a response, as expected:

```
 Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 120-145-525
```

Next, I install the `Pyngrok` package and store the contents of it in a folder called ngrok in my CWD as stated in the ngrok documentation (https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

But when I then run `ngrok http 5000` in my terminal, I get the error:

```
no such file or directory
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: maybe you have to use `/full/path/to/ngrok http 500`

Comment: Thanks furas, I tried it but I got a zsh: permission denied error. But I am not trying to modify the file, so any ideas why I am getting this error

Comment: You didn't show FULL error message so I don't know what system you use. On Linux/Unix/Mac files have permissions `read`, `write`, `execute`. You may not have permission to execute it. It also may not execute it if file has no permission to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the Pyngrok package for this. ngrok is a stand-alone executable and trying to use it via a pip installation is perhaps causing you issues with your `PATH`.

I would recommend [installing ngrok by following the instructions here](https://ngrok.com/download). There are different ways of installing for your operating system.

If you go the route of downloading and unzipping the package, make sure to place the executable in a directory that is in your `PATH`, for example `/usr/local/bin` on Mac.

Otherwise, you can run the executable from the folder you unzip it to by navigating to that directory on the command line and calling `./ngrok http 5000`.

Comment: Thanks philnash, still new to a lot of this! Will give it a try :)